# Heavy Screen Glitching and Flickering (22.04LTS) (AMD APU)

Tags: drivers, graphics, multiple-monitors, ssd, amd-graphics

Im fairly new to Ubuntu, and freshly installed Ubuntu 22.04LTS to my HP laptop (AMD Ryzen 5500U, 8GB RAM, 1TB SSD). I have it dually booted with Windows (same SSD in a different partition, as I can't install another SSD in my laptop)

Ever since I installed Ubuntu im getting this heavy screen glitches. My laptop doesn't have any graphics card so it im using the APU drivers for Radeon Graphics.

I don't seem to find any reason for this glitching to happen. It is neither Xorg or Wayland as it happens in both type of sessions, resolution and frecuency changes don't do anything neither, night light doesn't seems to affect in any way, maybe high CPU usage (I couldn't prove that yet) or high temperatures? I like Ubuntu but this glitching is pissing me off tbh. Help!

(Image embedded, the glitching is not constant, as it flickers a lot, thanks god Im not epileptic lmao)

[Glitch image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1IDzD.jpg)